# Why would you use a backdrop on location?

Tags: portrait, backdrops

I see in behind-the-scenes shots of many famous photographers that they shoot with a backdrop but on location. For example a National Geographic photographer I follow had just posted one of him with an oliphant backdrop in middle of a mountain.

So my question is in this case how are they using it? If the subject is going to be fully in front of the backdrop then why not shoot in studio? or maybe their assignment includes some environmental shots and some studio shots? so they just take the backdrop on location?

For example, see this [photo of filmmaker Tony Armer](http://felixkunze.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/FKP0109-final-Tony-Armer-by-Felix-Kunze.jpg) by Felix Kunze.

Comment: You may want to attribute the image to [Tony Armer](http://tonyarmer.com/), and link instead of posting the image, given that images on SE should be Creative Commons-share alike.

Comment: Maybe they do it for the fun behind-the-scenes shots?

Comment: @inkista : Still don't know him :) but yes I added his name to the question! I knew the photographer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular instance, we don't have to speculate why the photographer used the backdrop on location. In [Felix's own words](http://felixkunze.com/tony-armer/):

> This is taking location lighting to a new level. I put one of my Oliphant backdrops up in a field and I used daylight as a basis and then added in my own lighting to ‘kick it’ a little.
>
> So we end up with this clean studio look for these shots of Tony.